# Why are two Windows Phone emulators launching at once?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone

Recently I noticed that every time I launch a WP8 app from Visual Studio 2012, I get two emulators launching at the same time.  If I close either one, it will relaunch on next debug.  I have the VS2013 preview installed (not sure if that matters) and I have the newest version of the WP SDK installed.  This is running on Windows 8 Pro.  All my Google/Binging yielded no answers (or even other people asking the question!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution turned out to be simple.  I have the main phone app project along with some phone class library projects.  Well, that's what I thought!  It turns out that one of the class libraries had been created as an Application project instead!  Now I need to convert/recreate the project as a library.

In other words, today I learned that you can have two WP apps in the same solution and debug them at the same time on different emulators!